# How to hide Iterator and container implemtation in a custom class (w/o boost)

Tags: c++, c++11, implementation

I have been wracking my brain over this for the last day or so.  I am trying to figure out how to return an iterator from a class while hiding the type of container the class is using.  An example would be I have a class canvas that holds widgets with the same interface and they are stored privately in a std::vector.  So....

*Simplified code*

```
class Canvas  
{  
public:  
    WidgetIterator begin();  
    WidgetIterator end();  
private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> mImpl;  
};

class Canvas::Impl  
{
public:  
    std::vector<widget> mWidget;  
    //how to return mWidget.begin(), mWidget.end() up as widget iterator??  
}  

usage:  
int main()  
{  
    Canvas canvas();
    ...Fill canvas with widgets...  
    //iterate over widgets  
    for(auto& a_widget : canvas)  
    {  
        //do something with / to a_widget.  User does not know or care  
        //that underlying iterator is std::vector<widget>::iterator 
    }  
    ...Do more stuff....  
    return 0;  
}
```

Basically, I would like to somehow alias mWidget.begin() and mWidget.end() up through Canvas::begin() and Canvas::end().  The user knows that the iterator is to a widget, they just don't need to know that the iterator is std::vector::iterator.  I am trying to both hide my implementations using PIMPL and keep information about how things are stored within the class.

I can't seem to find the right "formula".  I have looked at type-erasure and trying to return function pointers through an interface, but I can't seem to think of a way to keep std::vector::iterator out of the header, and everything I have seen so far in looking this up don't seem to fit what I am trying to do.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Reading material?  Is there a concept I am missing?  Oh - and I have seen some use boost int he examples that I couldn't figure out how to make work in my situation.  I would like to avoid that because I am trying to reduce outside dependencies.

Comment: can't you just *document* that your WidgetIterator is an *unspecified* random access iterator (or whatever iterator category you want it to be)  ? for example, the standard library does not impose special restrictions on its iterator types other than those imposed by the iterator concept ( for instance, a vector<>::iterator may be just a pointer ) ...

Comment: Implement you own iterator.  It can use a std::vector iterator internally, or not.  An iterator has to implement very few "functions" to be usable.

Comment: So iteration is a very intensive process that involves lots of interaction with the iterator.  Are you ok with heavy performance hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to type erase an iterator is to write an input iterator generator.

This is enough to `for(:)` loop, but not all other algorithms, and can wrap any random-access container easily:

```
template<class T>
struct gen_iterator_t {
  std::function<T(std::size_t)> f;
  std::size_t n = 0;
  gen_iterator& operator++() { ++n; return *this; }
  gen_iterator operator++(int) { auto r = *this; ++*this; return r; }
  T operator*() { return f(n); }
  gen_iterator_t( gen_iterator_t const& )=default;
  gen_iterator_t( gen_iterator_t && )=default;
  gen_iterator_t& operator=( gen_iterator_t const& )=default;
  gen_iterator_t& operator=( gen_iterator_t && )=default;
  gen_iterator_t()=default;

  explicit operator bool() const { return static_cast<bool>(f); }

  gen_iterator_t( std::function<T(std::size_t)> fin, std::size_t i ):
    f(fin), n(i)
  {}

  friend bool operator==( gen_iterator_t const& lhs, gen_iterator_t const& rhs ) {
    if (!lhs && !rhs) return true;
    if (!lhs || !rhs) return false;
    return lhs.n == rhs.n;
  }
  friend bool operator==( gen_iterator_t const& lhs, gen_iterator_t const& rhs ) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
};
```

we then write `range`:

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It s, It f ) { return {s,f}; }
```

and generate range:

```
template<class F>
range_t< gen_iterator_t< std::result_of_t<F&(std::size_t)> > >
generate_range( F f, std::size_t start, std::size_t finish ) {
  return { {f, start}, {f, finish} };
}
```

now your class exposes

```
class Canvas {
public:
  range_t< gen_iterator_t< widget& > > get_widgets();
};
```

which is implemented as

```
range_t< gen_iterator_t< widget& > > Canvas::get_widgets() {
  return generate_range(
    [this]( std::size_t n )->widget& { return mImpl->mWidget[n]; },
    0, mImpl->mWidget.size()
  );
}
```

and little is exposed.

If you want to go a step further and have it able to wrap non-random access containers that is a bit more work.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer.  It has given me the concept and pointed me in the direction I want to go.   Much appreciated!